# SparkContext cannot read file which stored in HDFS however command "hadoop fs -text" can read it correctly

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

As mentioed before, there are some files which are stored in HDFS.

`sc.textFile` method cannot read them correctly but `hadoop fs -text` can.

`sc.textFile("hdfs://destinationFile...")`.first will return messy code.

[messycode return from sc.textFile().first.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOQqB.png)

Is there any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Your hadoop shell client and spark read files with different decompression codec. Try rename your file with a correct extension.
Reference: [Reading Compressed Data With Spark Using Unknown File Extensions](http://arjon.es/2015/10/02/reading-compressed-data-with-spark-using-unknown-file-extensions/)